# SEO Friendly URL on dynamic product page produced via shortcode

Tags: plugins, permalinks, shortcode, seo, mod-rewrite

I have created a product page in wordpress, /product.

This currently takes the id of a product /product/?id=123

The page has a shortcode that then fetches and displays the relevent data

e.g.
[product_shortcode]

I'm wondering how I can make this URL more SEO friendly. I've tried using a URL Rewrite via .htaccess so that I could link to the pages like so; /product/id/product-description

However Wordpress throws a 404 even though I can see some of my shortcode runs (the title tag changes)

Can anyone advise how I can achieve what I'm trying to do here? Been at it for 2 weeks! :(

Comment: OK so I've worked out what the true unfriendly URL is by disabling permalinks. I now have this rule: `add_rewrite_rule('^product\/(\d+)\/.*','index.php?page_id=5&id=$matches[1]','top');`   Which redirects me to the homepage. Why? Also, if I re-enable permalinks it 404's. Can you not have custom rewrites with permalinks enabled? I'm very confused.

Comment: Pretty Permalinks definitely need to be enabled for rewrite rules to work. Did you flush rewrites after adding your rule?

Comment: I did yes. Everytime I've changed them I've clicked 'save permalinks'.

Comment: I've installed a 'Rewrite analyzer' plugin, which doesn't seem to match the condition. Though having said that nothing seems to match which seems odd. Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/rSyJO4C

Comment: Nothing wrong there, visiting `domain.com/p/` wouldn't be anything other than a page in your case, seems totally normal.

Comment: OK but shouldnt domain.com/product/123/abc match my rule. it does not.

Comment: There's a syntax error somewhere in your rule, it throws a notice when I visit the rewrite analyzer page with debugging enabled.

Comment: obviously the syntax is a tad different but it seems to work here: https://regex101.com/r/5hniR0/5

Comment: Updated again taking out the first group. As far as I'm concerned that should work. I've tried taking out the escaping backslahes too. https://regex101.com/r/5hniR0/6

Comment: The rule I posted works if you just add whatever additional chars you need into the first capture group. I can’t test your new rules at the moment.

Comment: Nice one mate. Getting somewhere now. It seems Wordpress didn't like \d or \w. So I've changed it to be like product/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9-_/]+)/?$  which seems to work. However It's then getting rewritten again by the permalink rules in wordpress, to be the post title and losing the information i'm passing in querystring. How can I prevent it doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your rule needs a little tweak. You also need to add `id` to valid query vars.

```
function wpd_test_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%id%', '([0-9]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^product/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?page_id=5&id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_test_rule' );
```

Note that WordPress doesn't put query vars in `$_GET`, you'll need to adjust your code to use `get_query_var('id')` to fetch the value. I'd also consider using something more unique than `id`.

Comment: I had registered the query variable using add_filter('query_vars' previously. I've amended the code to what you've provided and still no cigar. I had to alter it slightly because the id is alphanumeric and can contain underscores. Also some text can follow it, ie the product description so doesn't it need to be like this?  `'^detail/(d+)/.*?$', 'index.php?name=detail&id=$matches[1]'` thanks for your help mate